# E-commerce theme development in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, e-commerce

I am learning WordPress and I know how to edit and develop a site from available templates, now I am trying to make a custom e-commerce template from scratch, and I couldn't find any tutorials available. Will you please suggest me a video tutorial which will be helpful for me to reffer and develop the template.

Comment: I am trying to build it from scratch using php

Comment: Batz is right - you need to decide what plugin you using for wordpress e-commerce and then work with that. Woocommerce is the most obvious place to start because its the most popular option.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a child theme on WooCommerce plugin https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203105897-How-to-set-up-and-use-a-child-theme